# Using pow in php

Tags: php, math, pow

Hi can I use pow instead of writing it like this?

```
                    $round1 = $max / 2;
                    $round2 = $round1 + ($max / 2 / 2);
                    $round3 = $round2 + ($max / 2 / 2 / 2);
                    $round4 = $round3 + ($max / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2);
                    $round5 ...
                    $final = $max - 1;
                    $third = $max;
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Maybe add some kind of explanation of your expected output etc?

Comment: Dividing by 2 is equivalent to shifting right by one: `$max >> 1` is identical to `$max / 2`.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't happen to be looking for an easier way to do this, would you:

```
$round = array($max/2);
for ($i=1;i<$max;$i++)
{
    $round[] = $round[$i -1] + $max/pow(2, $i + 1);
}
```

Of course, `array_sum` might be worth a peek, too.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
 $rount[0]=0;
 for($i=1;$1<upto n rounds;$i++)
 {
   $rount[i]=$round[i-1]+($max/(2*i));
 }
```

Comment: this is correct for `i` = 1 or 2 but `($max/2/2/2) != ($max/(2*3))` and will not work following this.